# What is industry standard for when to push/pull between core data and remote database

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization

Only been programming for a couple months now and am finally ready to build a full fledged app.  I was wondering, for an app like say Wunderlist (a to do list), what are the industry standards for when to pull/push data between the remote server and core data (where I assume all local data is stored).

Obviously upon sign in a pull is a no brainer.  But thereafter how often should I push local changes into cloud?  Whenever they are made?  And if I plan to eventually make a website from which a user can instantly save changes to the server, how often should I pull updates to the phone (or should I instead learn about websockets and thus push from server whenever changes are made)?

Also I imagine I'll find quite a bit googling around on this, but if anybody can point to where to go to learn how to actually manage the syncing that would be really helpful. All help appreciated!

Comment: you have any input screen from where you have to send data to server or just fetch data from server and display it in app ?

Comment: Send and fetch both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly depending on your use case. Let's assume two different options:

1. Data changes on both sites (or on one site), but is not time-sensitive. The user doesn't regualarly switch between multiple systems or doesn't expect all sites to be directly in sync. In this case you would implement a standard pull-to-reload and push-on-completion behavior (e.g comments on a news-plattform)
2. Data changes on both sites and is time-sensitive, because the user is switching between Desktop/Browser and your Mobile Application. A good example for this is Apples Notes Application. You can use this on multiple Devices (iPad/iPhone/Mac) and switch between these (on good days).

**Option 1** seems to be what you are currently working with. Switching to **Option 2** has many possible solutions with different trade-offs. My favorite approach to solve the problem of inconsistencies is sending [silent-push](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) notifications to all devices when assuming that the user will soon switch to a different device (e.g. leaving a ToDo-Elements ViewController in a ToDo-List app). For this approach you'll have to implement a push-service on your WebServer with an own API to queue your notifications and distinguish them by their user/data.